# Whitelist HTML tags for ReactMarkdown

Tags: reactjs, remarkjs, react-markdown, rehypejs

I have been happily using ReactMarkdown and I was wondering what is the easiest way to passthrough a whitelisted selection of HTML tags.

Let's use the `kbd` element for now as an example. I have this markdown:

```
Please press key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
```

For obvious safety reasons, ReactMarkdown escapes `<kbd>` and `</kbd>` and it does not render as `kbd` HTML elements.

I know I can use the plugin rehype-raw, but is very large and I don't need to support the whole HTML: I would be happy with a compact yet brittle regexp-based implementation.

My understanding is that I have two options:

- make a remark plugin: I could make up a markdown extension (e.g. `[kbd CTRL]`) and create a custom plugin that generates `kdb` elements
- make a rehype plugin: I could parse the html generated by ReactMarkdown and create some nodes on the fly

In concrete terms, my questions are:

- should I make a remark plugin, a rehype plugin, or something else?
- could anyone share a simple code snippet to do this? I already spent some time parsing the code of some plugins, but I could not figure out how to add nodes.